# Xero API - How do I retrieve individual contact with ContactID?

Tags: c#, xero-api

I can retrieve all contact list but how can i retrieve single contact list by contact ID? I'm using c# code. Please see my below code. I'm trying below way but its not working. I need to send request like this url.

```
GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts/e8000dd0-3a27-4a2d-bc54-a451a1d14cea
```

I try to send request below way but its pulling all contact. **I need to pull out an individual contact.** How can achieve that? how can pass my parameter like request.AddQueryParameter("ContactID", "e8000dd0-3a27-4a2d-bc54-a451a1d14cea");

```
var request = new RestRequest(_apiMethod, Method.GET); // _apiMethod=contacts

request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", filter.AuthToken));
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Xero-tenant-id", filter.TenantId);

request.AddParameter("ContactID", "e8000dd0-3a27-4a2d-bc54-a451a1d14cea", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddQueryParameter("ContactID", "e8000dd0-3a27-4a2d-bc54-a451a1d14cea");
```

Thanks in Advance !

Kind Regards,
Liton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve this issue with below code sample

```
   var client = new RestClient(BaseUrl);
   var method = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", _apiMethod, "e8000dd0-3a27-4a2d-bc54-a451a1d14cea");
   var request = new RestRequest(method, Method.GET);
```

I'm sending contactId below way

```
var method = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", _apiMethod, ContactId);
```

Thanks !